# Change a continuous axis' labels to be strings

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a line chart in ggplot2 with a continuous y-axis but I would like to change the labels to strings to represent bounds, is this possible?

For example, I want all values V<10 = A, 10>V<20 = B, and V>20 = C.

```r
Y<-c(5,15,12,8,12,13,19,24)
Day<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
data <- data.frame(Y, Day)
ggplot(data= data, aes(x=Day, y=Y, group=1))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

The label of 10 would be replaced by A, 20 by B and so on.

Comment: Hi Olli, yes, it's possible, but your description of what you want isn't clear enough to allow for a demonstration. Could you edit your question to give a minimal reproducible example, including a sample of your data, your current code, and a clearer description of what you want your plot to look like?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Apologies, I have now updated the question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `scale_y_continuous` and relabel the scale using the `labels=` argument.  The key here is to also use `breaks=` which map back to the original numeric scale and then I'm also using `limits=` to ensure that we can see the whole alphabet.

```
ggplot(data= data, aes(x=Day, y=Y, group=1))+geom_line()+geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=LETTERS, breaks=1:26, limits=c(1,26))
```

[image]